# Densityplots using colwise - different colors for each line?

Tags: r, plyr, kernel-density

I need a plot of different density lines, each in another color. This is an example code (but much smaller), using the built-in data.fame `USArrests`. I hope it is ok to use it?

```
colors <- heat.colors(3)  
plot(density(USArrests[,2], bw=1, kernel="epanechnikov", na.rm=TRUE),col=colors[1])     
lines1E <- function(x)lines(density(x,bw=1,kernel="epanechnikov",na.rm=TRUE))    
lines1EUSA <- colwise(lines1E)(USArrests[,3:4])`
```

Currently the code produces with `colwise()` just one color. How can I get each line with another color? Or is there ab better way to plot several density lines with different colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite follow your example, so I've created my own example data set. First, create a matrix with three columns:

```
m = matrix(rnorm(60), ncol=3)
```

Then plot the density of the first column:

```
plot(density(m[,1]), col=2)
```

Using your `lines1E` function as a template:

```
lines1E = function(x) {lines(density(x))}
```

We can add multiple curves to the plot:

```
colwise(lines1E)(as.data.frame(m[ ,2:3]))
```

---

Personally, I would just use:

```
##Added in NA for illustration
m = matrix(rnorm(60), ncol=3)
m[1,] = NA
plot(density(m[,1], na.rm=T))
sapply(2:ncol(m), function(i) lines(density(m[,i], na.rm=T), col=i))
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. With your first example I still have just 2 colors, instead of 3. My original data.frame is much larger. sapply didn't work with my data.frame, I think because of the NA's, this is why I used colwise() instead. But I will try again

Comment: 'NA's don't affect `sapply`. However, you will need to add `na.rm=TRUE` in the density function. Regarding the colours, that is bit more tricky, since it would require your `lines1E` function to know what column is being used. It is possible, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: This works - thank you very much! I think I didn't use the sapply function correct in the first place.